# Error using Ruby OR in if

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this simple condition in my ruby code:

```
if user.text != ("Empty" || "Damaged")
```

do something...

the thing is that when it is "Damaged" it still enters the loop, so I have to use this:

```
if user.text != "Empty"
    if user.text != "Damaged"
...
..
```

What is the correct syntax to make the first one work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
unless ["Empty", "Damaged"].include?(user.text)
  ...
end
```

The problem with your first approach is that `a || b` means that: if `a != nil` then it is `a`, else it is `b`. As you can see it is good for variables, not constants as they are rarely nil. Your expression `("Empty" || "Damaged")` simply equals `"Empty"`.

You want to use the this as a binary operator, the correct form would be:

```
if (user.text != "Empty") && (user.text != "Damaged")
```

The upper solution is just shorter. It consists of an array of elements you want to avoid, and you just simply check is the `user.text` is not present in it.

Answer (score 2):

@Matzi has the right answer, for sure. But here's why what you're doing is failing:

Your statement `("Empty" || "Damaged")` evaluates to "Empty"

You're saying return either one of these, whichever non-false thing you find first. In Ruby, any string, number or Object returns true, so you return "Empty" every time.

A better way to lay it out if you really want to use an if statement:

```
if user.text != "Empty" && user.text != "Damaged"
  ...
end
```

I assume, by the way, that you're trying to say "If the user text is neither Damaged nor Empty".

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was just editing my post to add this when you wrote yours. But you are right. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

if ((text != "Empty") && (text != "Damaged"))